# CSS and the float property

Tags: css, web-applications

I'm trying to make a CSS/javascript dropdown menu (based on [this example](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/). This works. But I want to have a background color for my whole menu. I tried to place the `<ul>` inside a div and give this div a background color. However, the actual menu items do not appear inside the div when I view the page, they are under it. After some experimenting, I found out that this was caused by setting `float: left;` on the `li` elements that comprises the main menu items. (of cause, taking `float: left;` away means that the menu items are stacked on top of eachother in stead of side by side).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post post your markup and css? Here's a good article about floats, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: why to put the ul in a div and then give background for div, and don't give background for ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a background color for your main menu items, you can add `overflow:auto;` or `float:left;` to the containing div tag.

If you want to set the background color of the sub-items, add it to the `li ul` rule.

Brief example here: http://www.danfsmith.com/so/css/suckerfish/menu.html

Comment: Thank you! `overflow: auto` made the div get a scrollbar when hovering the menu item, but `float:left` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to set a background color for each link in your dropdown menu. If you create the menu with:

```
<ul class="navigation"> 
<li id="youarehere"><a href="http://example.com">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/blog/">Blog</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/papers.html">Papers</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/programs.html">Programs</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/activities.html">Activities</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://example.com/about.html">About</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Then the CSS to set the background color is:

```
ul.navigation li a {
    width: 111px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    background-color: #993333;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 0px #fff;
    border-top: solid 0px #fff;
    border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the CSS property `overflow: auto;` to your `<div/>` or `<ul/>` which has the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background colour for the div to show you'll need to clear the floats.

```
<div style="background-color: red">
<ul>
<li>asda</li>
<li>asd</li>
<li>asd</li>
<li>asd</li>
<li>asd</li>
</ul>
 <span style="clear: both"></span>
</div>
```

Notice the span with the "clear: both" style in. That should do it.

Heres a link to a nice quirks mode post about it

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html